# Kolla-ansible deployment fails

Tags: kolla-ansible

I tried to use Kolla-ansible to deploy all-in-one OpenStack for Ubuntu 20.04LTS and the following error was reported.

```
TASK [service-rabbitmq : nova | Ensure RabbitMQ users exist] *******************
failed: ...
    "msg": "Could not determine the version of the RabbitMQ server."
```

What should I do, or should I ask for help elsewhere? I couldn't find the Kolla-ansible community forum :(

Thank you!   (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with kolla-ansible during my deployment today,
You can follow the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kolla-ansible/+bug/1946506